# Replace characters from string without changing its object_id in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How can I replace characters from string without changing its `object_id`?

For example:

```
string = "this is a test"
```

The first 7 characters need to be replaced with capitalized characters like: `"THIS IS a Test"` and the `object_id` needs to be the same. In which way can I sub or replace the characters to make it happen?

Comment: You should better replace your entire question with correct capitalization, otherwise, it will be downvoted.

Comment: This is what is sometimes called a [lazy question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar). It appears you are competent in writing correct English, but can't be bothered to do so, by not capitalizing, omitting punctuation and misspelling words. It's too bad, as it's a descent question. Being old-school, I would have written "seven characters" (because the number is less than 10) and "substitute", but I won't fault you for that, except for the misspelling of "characters".

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
string = "this is a test"
string[0, 7] = string[0, 7].upcase
```

Comment: this first object_id is 6911740 and the second one is 6911620. so it changed, my question is find a way to change the string without change its object_id

Comment: The second string is not the first one. If you hate this answer, I will delete it within thirty minutes.

Comment: It appears that sai does not hate you answer, but even if he/she did, so what? Your answer is for all readers. If you are correct and someone doesn't like it, that's their problem,  not yours.

Answer (score 1):

With procedural languages, one might write the equivalent of:

```
string = "this is in jest"
string.object_id
  #=> 70309969974760 
(1..7).each { |i| string[i] = string[i].upcase }
  #=> 1..7 
string
  #=> "tHIS IS in jest" 
string.object_id
  #=> 70309969974760
```

This is not very Ruby-like, but it does offer the advantage over @sawa's solution that it does not create a temporary 7-character string. (Well, it does create a one-character string.) This is unimportant for strings of reasonable length (and for those I'd certainly concur with sawa), but it could be significant for really, really, really long strings.

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
string.each_char.with_index { |c,i|
  string[i] = string[i].upcase if (1..7).cover?(i) }
  #=> "tHIS IS in jest" 
string.object_id
  #=> 70309969974760
```

This second way might be more efficient if `string` is not much larger than `string[start_index..end_index]`.

**Edit:**

In a comment the OP indicates that the string is to be stripped, squeeze and reversed as well as certain characters converted to upper case. That could be done on the string in place, without creating a copy, as follows:

```
def strip_upcase_squeeze_reverse_whew(string, upcase_range, squeeze_str=nil)
  string.strip!
  upcase_range.each { |i| string[i] = string[i].upcase }
  squeeze_str.nil? ? string.squeeze! : string.squeeze!(squeeze_str)
  string.reverse!
end
```

I have assumed the four operations would be performed in a particular order, but if the order should be different, that's an easy fix.

```
string = " this may bee inn jest, butt it's alsoo a test  "
string.object_id
  #=> 70309970103280 
strip_upcase_squeeze_reverse_whew(string, (1..7))
  #=> "tset a osla s'ti tub ,tsej ni eb YAM SIHt"
string.object_id
  #=> 70309970103280
```

The steps:

```
string = "this may bee inn jest, butt it's alsoo a test"
  #=> "this may bee inn jest, butt it's alsoo a test" 
upcase_range = (1..7)
  #=> 1..7 
string.strip!
  #=> nil 
string
  #=> "this may bee inn jest, butt it's alsoo a test" 
upcase_range.each { |i| string[i] = string[i].upcase }
  #=> 1..7 
string
  #=> "tHIS MAY bee inn jest, butt it's alsoo a test" 
squeeze_str.nil? ? string.squeeze! : string.squeeze!(squeeze_str)
  #=> "tHIS MAY be in jest, but it's also a test" 
string    
  #=> "tHIS MAY be in jest, but it's also a test" 
string.reverse!
  #=> "tset a osla s'ti tub ,tsej ni eb YAM SIHt"
```

Notice that in this example, `strip!` does not remove any characters, and therefore returns `nil`. Similarly, `squeeze!` would return `nil` if there is nothing to squeeze.  It is for that reason that `strip!` and `squeeze` cannot be chained.

A second example:

```
string = "  thiiiis may beeee in jeeest"
strip_upcase_squeeze_reverse_whew(string, (12..14), "aeiouAEIOU")
```

Comment: Thanks Cary  for you answer. this method actually work for the example here, but the actually one i want to do, it require strip, reverse, squeeze and then upcase all togehter.  it looks like the this method wouldn;t on the reverse. I am sorry for not providing all detail initially. but more importantly, the concept to keep the object_id the same is to not create a temp  character?

Comment: Thanks Cary again for all work.  the order is  strip, reverse, squeeze and then upcase, but it only apply to the first 7 charters, the rest of the string will remain  the same. so it your example, "y bee inn jest, butt it's alsoo a test" remains unchanged.  I am sorry if i didn't make this clear. i didn't think this would be that complicated, i am kind of new to Ruby and def function still a bit new to me, but it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

#### Adding onto a string without changing its object id:

```
foo = "foo"
  # => "foo"

foo.object_id
  # => 70196045363960

foo << "bar"
  # => "foobar"

foo.object_id
  # => 70196045363960
```

#### Replace an entire string without changing its object id

```
foo
  # => "foo"

foo.object_id
  # => 70196045363960

foo.gsub!(/./, '') << 'bar'
 # => 'bar'

foo.object_id
  # => 70196045363960
```

#### Replace part of a string without changing its object id

```
foo
  # => "foo"

foo.object_id
  # => 70196045363960

foo.gsub!(/o/, 'z')
 # => 'fzz'

foo.object_id
  # => 70196045363960
```